# How show active call between sip to sip in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, sip, phone-call

When I type "core show channels" I get a channel for the current calls through DAHDI but I want see calls between sip to sip too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://asternic.org or some other panel project already writed.

btw, core show channels show all calls, including sip. If you not see sip calls, you have set on your peer

```
canreinvite=no
```